# Validate failed: Detected applied migration not resolved locally | Flyway

Tags: database, spring-boot, migration, database-migration, flyway

While setting up flyway i am getting this error in my spring-boot app

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Validate failed: Detected applied migration not resolved locally: 1.5.4

properties file

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl_auto=update
spring.jpa.hibernate.use-new-id-generator-mappings=false
spring.flyway.locations=classpath:db/migration,classpath:db/vendor/mysql
spring.flyway.baseline-on-migrate=true
spring.flyway.baseline-version=1.0.2
spring.flyway.table=schema_version
spring.flyway.enabled=true
```

The above configuration is working fine with other project.

i tried adding this plugin in my pom.xml but still its not working

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
        <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <argline>${argline} flyway:migrate -Dflyway.ignoreMissingMigrations=true</argline>
        </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Your database has a version `1.5.4` which might have been deleted from project. Just confirm if you still `1.5.4` available in project

Comment: yes i just found its not present there , Thanks @SukhpalSingh , so i have ignored the previous versions in configuration

Comment: If this version is not needed anymore, you can delete row in schema_version (flyway database table) who declare/search for it (column version)

Answer (score 9):

you can fix your issue by executing this command in your local db.

```
delete from flyway_schema_history where version = '1.5.4'
```

Comment: What if I just gonna to deploy a release branch which does not contain new version script, but on master branch I've migrated the newest version script to db?

Answer (score 6):

I've met this problem when deploy release branch which cherry pick some commit from master.

I've fixed this by add properties:

```
spring:
  flyway:
    ignore-missing-migrations: true
```

Please refer to https://flywaydb.org/documentation/configuration/parameters/ignoreMissingMigrations
and https://flywaydb.org/documentation/configuration/parameters/outOfOrder.

You can add outOfOrder option to migrate old version sql script at the next cherry-pick (which cherry pick the older commits):

```
spring:
  flyway:
    ignore-missing-migrations: true
    out-of-order: true
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a configuration file, try to use this:

```
flyway.outOfOrder=true
flyway.ignoreMissingMigrations=true
```

Answer (score 0):

may be you  mistakely delete the V_sql file in db/migration in project, it doesnt match with the checksum in the flyway_scheme_history. To me, I go to and delete that line from database